# Marking content as creative commons for search engines

Tags: creative-commons

Google Advanced search provides the ability to search for data with certain usage rights (creative commons). How can I tag my data to indicate the usage rights?

Comment: For reference: Similar question on [opensource.se]: [*How do search engines read image licence?*](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4654/138)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [license chooser generator](http://creativecommons.org/choose/) on the [creativecommons.org](http://creativecommons.org/) website. The [generator](http://creativecommons.org/choose/) helps you chose the correct licence and then will generate a code for you to add to your page.

There is also more information on licence mark up best practices on the page below:

[Best Practices for Marking Content with CC Licenses: Creators](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Marking/Creators)

Comment: So, you just need to link using `rel="licence"` to the correct URL <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.en_US"